# Is there way to force apps to start in specific order at login?

Tags: macos, login

Like everyone else, I've got a few apps that start automatically when I login. Some of these connect to the Internet. I'm using a VPN consistently, and some of these apps boot up and login before my VPN is running.

Is there a way to specify the starting order of the login apps and delay the start so that the VPN has a chance to connect first?

Comment: Are they in Login Items, or launched by .plist?

Comment: Some are login items, others launched by .plists in <Userlibrary>/LaunchAgents, /Library/LaunchAgents or /Library/LaunchDaemons. None of them seem to be in /System/Library/Launch(Agents/Daemons)

Comment: idk how to do .plists, but Login Items start up in the list order. The only way I know of to change the order, unfortunately, is to add them in that order.

Comment: Instead of letting MacOS start the apps, you could make a shell-/Apple-/Automator script which opens the apps one by one, and then let this script be run on login